# I am using Node.JS and there is a mistake in expecting ')'. Please how can i solve it

Tags: node.js

```
`<h2>Hobbies</h2>
    <ul>
        <%= data.hobby.forEach(function(item)
    { %>
        <li>
            <%= item %>
        </li>
        <%
    }); %>
    `
```

here is the mistake : SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in C:\src\express\views\profile.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you have added = before foreach.that's the issue. remove that = sign. & you code will work.

```
`<h2>Hobbies</h2>
<ul>
    <% data.hobby.forEach(function(item)
{ %>
    <li>
        <%= item %>
    </li>
    <%
}); %>
```

Reference:
https://ejs.co/#docs

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "%>" and "<%" inside the function I would make it return a string with the desired content.

Comment: he added = before foreach loop.that's why he got the issue